# How is "have half a mind to do X" commonly expressed in Russian?

Tags: выражения

> e.g.: I’**ve half a mind to** quit my job right here and now -- only if I'm already set for life, that is...
>
> or: I’**ve a good mind to** quit my job right here and now -- only if I'm already set for life, that is...

This English expression is used in a rather disapproving, threatening tone, even if half-jokingly, when you are faced with something unpleasant. It also implies that you are not likely to follow through with the threat you've made or whatever action you just said you were going to do, after all.

How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in Russian? I asked around, but it seems the expression cannot be easily rendered in Russian.

Answer (score 2):

- если тон шутливый, или вы говорите с тем, кому доверяете:

  > ... подумываю сменить работу.
- более неформальная, чисто разговорная форма,
  желание возникло и продолжается или возникает (появляется) время от времени:

> ... [хочется сменить работу](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=I%20have%20a%20mind%20to).

-

> half mind

обычно переводится другим выражением, в случае желания сменить работу не подходящим, -

> иметь склонность (в своей природе/по своему характеру, а не под воздействием обстоятельств)

https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=have%20half%20a%20mind%20to%20do

https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?a=3&sc=0&s=half%20mind&l1=1&l2=2

Answer (score 1):

Well, when speaking with no affectation, one way it could be rendered in i guess is

**Я уже готов / настроен (сделать что-л.)**

If there's a condition under which it would be possible then also

**Я был бы уже готов (сделать что-л.)**

Comment: "И бросил бы, да жить не на что"

Answer (score 1):

Я *на грани того, чтобы* уволиться с этой работы.

Я был *на грани того, чтобы* дать ему в морду.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just translate it near verbatim: "Я уже наполовину решил бросить свою работу", "Одна половина моего мозга говорит мне уволиться", "Добрая половина меня склоняется к тому, чтобы уволиться".